# Would magento use JSONB over EAV?

Tags: postgresql, magento, entity-attribute-value, jsonb

http://coussej.github.io/2016/01/14/Replacing-EAV-with-JSONB-in-PostgreSQL/

says jsonb is faster than EAV.

Wonder if that conclusion is over simplified?

We are creating a marketplace where I need to support many types of products.

[Postgresql JSONB is coming. What to use now? Hstore? JSON? EAV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873476/postgresql-jsonb-is-coming-what-to-use-now-hstore-json-eav)

also favors JSON over EAV it seems...

So my question is, would magento be better off with JSONB than its use of EAV to describe product attributes?